# Send images through form php mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I want a form where users can upload an image. That image should  be shown on the mail as an attachment.

This is some reference code.

```
<?php

$name= $_POST['name'];
$photo= $_POST['photo'];

$mailTo = "test@hotmail.com";

$headers = "New mail\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

$message = "<html><head>
<title>Title</title>
</head> 
<body>

Name: $name <br>
Photo: $apellido 

<img src=\"http://www.myserver.com/images_folder/my_image.jpg\">
</body>"

mail($mailTo, 'New mail', $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: PHP's manual has a  section to guide you how to handle file upload [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423942/how-to-send-image-in-php-mail-function